# variable decimal digits

Tags: crystal-reports

I put the following formula in Custom Style->Decimals

Local stringVar strCadena :=ToText(cdbl({ado.ValorCliente}) - Truncate ({ado.ValorCliente}, 0));
Length (strCadena) - 2

But the report set 2 decimal for this operation ( 2 is equal to the setting configured in Regional Settings of my computer)
cdbl({ado.ValorCliente}) - Truncate ({ado.ValorCliente}, 0)

Is there a way to avoid the regional settings?

Thanks in advance.
Talo

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well, and here is the formula I used:

```
 if InStrRev(ToText({#Sum00}), ".") = 0 then
     0
 else 
     Length(Replace(TrimRight(Replace(Split(ToText({#Sum00},8), ".")[2],"0"," "))," ","0"))
```

Ugly but finally did what I needed without using any regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to display a numeric field in Crystal using the same precision as it was recorded in? 1.9, 2.3451, 23456.650000006, etc?
Assuming that the divider between the integer part of the number and the decimals is always a decimal point, this should work :

```
Local NumberVar dotPos := InstrRev({ado.ValorCliente}, ".");
If dotPos = 0 Then
    0 //returning 0
Else
    Len({ado.ValorCliente}) - dotPos
```

Comment: I'm using Crystal Report 8.5. and Len() function only accepts a string parameter. Then I used ToText() for data type conversion but crystal round my number with 2 decimal digits (Regional settings). I think I'm going to modify my query and return the numeric fields like string.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use format string parameter in ToText function? I can't check just now, but format string like next could work:

```
stringvar strUpToSixNonZeroDigitsAfterPoint := ToText(numSomeDecimalNumber, '#.######');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the custom styling, enter the following formula which converts the number to a string with a set number of decimal places, reverses it, then counts the number of digits until it reaches a non-zero and that's your decimal place:

```
Local NumberVar i := 0;
Local NumberVar p := 10;
Local NumberVar DP := 0;
For i := 1 To p Step 1 Do
If Mid(StrReverse(CStr(Sum({part_dims.weight}),p)),i,1) <> "0" Then (DP := (p+1)-i; Exit For);
DP
```

You can set *p* to anything, it represents the maximum number of decimal places.
There's probably an easier way of doing it but this works if your source values are of a numeric data type.